# AVPlayer Can't Play

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, avplayer

I want to play a remote mp3 with AVPlayer. I can't make it work and I can't see the reason why it doesn't work. Code:

```
NSString *urlstr=@"..some link to a mp3"
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
self.player = [[[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url] retain];
[player play];
```

The link is valid. If I load it in a webView it plays right away.
Please help.

Comment: There's a typo in your code: [NSURL URLWIthString:urlstr] instead of [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr]

Comment: in code is ok. typo is only here. my mistake.

Comment: Can you give an example of the url that you are using?  Note that it has to be to an mp3 file or something of that nature, not an HTML file with an MP3 embedded.

Comment: http://www.astation.fm/mp3/song.mp3 this is an example. something like this.

Comment: hi user282045 do you have get the solution for the problem? I am also facing the problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have get a solution. Please try the following code:

```
NSString *urlstr=@"http://www.3rdeyelab.com/mp3/mp3/tailtoddle_lo.mp3"
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
player = [[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem] retain];
[player play];
player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
```

Hope it will work for you!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you use a local link as URL, so you should initiate url with `fileURLWithPath` method:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlstr];
```

Answer (score 0):

The NSURLConnection class, regardless of whether the URL is local or remote, should always be used whenever a URL is concerned. It's the only thread-safe, non-intrusive means of loading a AVPlayerItem or AVAsset. Remember: your app shares the iPhone with other apps; and, this is the way to be responsible insodoing.