# How to play a music file using URL link in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, avfoundation

I want to play a music file using URL Link in the iPhone. But when I use the below code I am getting error I am not getting where I am going wrong. Can anyone Correct me?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 

{

[super viewDidLoad];
NSString* resourcePath = @"http://192.167.1.104:8888/SHREYA.mp3"; //your url

NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:resourcePath]];
NSError *error;


audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:_objectData error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);             

else 
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: @H2CO3 error during run time AudioPlayer[1012:10703] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteData baseURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7345540'
*** First throw call stack

Comment: You are trying to pass NSData to NSURL, that is giving you the error.  "initWithContentsOfURL:_objectData"

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper ok i corrected but still the error is AudioPlayer[1143:10703] Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)"

Comment: Try this: NSData *songFile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:songCacheURL options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error1 ];
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:songFile error:&error2];

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper No it doesnt work lot of error occurs

Comment: Ok then the only reason that occurs to me is that AVAudioPlayer doesn't support streaming via HTTP. Try using AVPlayer, may be that will help.

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper How do i do tat?

Comment: I have given the code in answer as it was too big for comment! check it out and tell if it helps...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"<#Live stream URL#>];

// You may find a test stream at <http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8>.

self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

//(optional) [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&ItemStatusContext];

self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:<#Live stream URL#>];

//(optional) [player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&PlayerStatusContext];
```

Use the following code to play the music:

`[self.player play];`

Comment: In the above code player is object of AVPlayer.what about playerITem?Bcoz i get so many errors.

Comment: self.playerItem is an object of AVPlayerItem and self.player is an object of AVPlayer

Comment: having error with undeclared &ItemsStatuscontext and PlayerstatusContext

Comment: [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&ItemStatusContext]; [player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&PlayerStatusContext]; are used to tell that you can perform any selector on the given funstions.. you may not use them...

Comment: I got it working with this code. I just have a question why do we set AVPlayer once by calling a constructor passing in a playerItem and then another time passing the NSURL. I wrote mine in swift just curious to why both are needed.

Comment: i have implemented this way , but its not playing any songs .

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 

{

[super viewDidLoad];
NSString* resourcePath = @"your url"; //your url

NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:resourcePath]];
NSError *error;


audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:_objectData error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 1;

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);             

else 
    [audioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Current Answer:

Now consider [Why does AVAudioPlayer initWithContentsOfURL always fail with error code=-43](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462728/ios-why-does-avaudioplayer-initwithcontentsofurl-always-fail-with-error-code) link. its solution is [avplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818254/avplayer-cant-play) link

Earlier Answer

```
//You have to pass NSURL not NSData
 NSString* resourcePath = @"http://192.167.1.104:8888/SHREYA.mp3"; //your url
 NSURL *url = [NSURL alloc]initWithString:resourcePath];
 audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url error:&error];

 audioPlayer.delegate = self;
 [url release];

 [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
 [audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: Thank u but still error is  AudioPlayer[1125:10703] Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)"

Comment: answer edited use initWithURL instead of initWithContentsOfURL

Comment: No still it doesnt work previous error is being repeated *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Answer (score 0):

Try my code:

```
NSURL *filepath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilePath];
 [yourMediaPlayer setContentURL:filepath];
  //set player.
  yourMediaPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
  yourMediaPlayer.currentPlaybackTime = 0;
  yourMediaPlayer.shouldAutoplay = FALSE;

  [yourMediaPlayer play];
```

^-^,I use MPMoviePlayerController with above code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are sending

```
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
```

to receive NSInvalidArgumentException  change it to

```
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 1;
```

and check apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/numberOfLoops)