# Playing audio using url is not working on iOS7

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

In my application, I have an audio url. I want to play the audio using that url on my device. It does not seem to be working.

Here is the code I am using.

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {

     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://jesusredeems.in/media/Media Advt/mp3_player/Songs/viduthalaiyin geethangal_vol1/93.Ellame Koodum.mp3"];

     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

     AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];

     [audioPlayer play];
}
```

I have used the above code. It's not working. Please tell me where I'm going wrong in the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add percentage escape in your query string, also you need to declare the AVAudioPlayer as a global variable.

So write the property in your class extension:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

And modify your method like:

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender
{
     NSString *urlstr = @"http://jesusredeems.in/media/Media Advt/mp3_player/Songs/viduthalaiyin geethangal_vol1/93.Ellame Koodum.mp3";
     urlstr = [urlstr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
     _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
     [_audioPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: @Midhum MP i have used ur code its audio is not playing it just showing the button selected for few minites its not working

Comment: @Midhum MP its playing but its taking too much time to play is there any way to make play fast

Comment: @user3614966: It is taking too much time, because you are downloading the file using synchronous method, you need something like audio streaming

Comment: @Midhum MP please suggest me how to do audio streaming because im new for the ios development

Comment: @user3614966: You can use the code mentioned here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716244/how-to-play-a-music-file-using-url-link-in-iphone

Comment: i also want to play the mp3 song from given url . i have followed all the codes with all the possible way but song just do not play . and i have referred your code also but nothing happen . so please guide me how do i play song using url link .

Comment: @Moxarth: Are you getting any error ? Can you post a new question with the issue you are facing ?

Comment: issue solved . thanks . your code works . i had some network issues and then appTransportSecurity error , just i used AVPlayer instead of AVAudioPlayer, and then it started working . thanks a lott .

Answer (score 1):

You need to add percentage encoding %20 of space in URL

```
  NSString *strURl=@"http://jesusredeems.in/media/Media Advt/mp3_player/Songs/viduthalaiyin geethangal_vol1/93.Ellame Koodum.mp3";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[strURl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

if still not working use delegate methods

```
audioPlayer = self;
```

USe delegate methods

```
 -(void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:
    (AVAudioPlayer *)player
                                    error:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }
```

Comment: Shan i have used ur code its audio is not playing it just showing the button selected for few minites its not working

Comment: Shan its playing but its taking too much time to play is there any way to make play fast

Comment: its depends on the internet connection but you can use to the background thread so it will not affect the main thread

Comment: Shan please tell suggest me some ideas about the background thread how to do it here as im new for the ios development im not aware of those things