# Which is the best way to save 100 songs ? AudioPlayer in iOS

Tags: ios7

Please, I have a question, 
I tried to make music App, But i have a question please:
If i have 100 song mp3, Which is the best way to save these songs ? ,I mean where must i add these files to prevent my App at become slowly when i run/play each song?

Best regards A.J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1) Save 100 songs in your app bundle

Pros - It will be fast to play/run the song
Cons - if App size will become more than 50 MB then your app will not install/download from iTunes without Wi-Fi connections

2) Save 100 songs at Server

Pros - App Size will not increased. User needs to download the song from server and saved document directory for future use.
Cons - You have to purchase server for hosting your files and APIs. User's data plan will be used in each download from server.

I would prefer you can go with first option if songs are fixed.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. Please, What do you mean ,if songs are fixed ? Thanks again, and I am sorry for delay.

Comment: Fixed means if number of songs those needs to be integrated.

Comment: Thanks sir. I will try the first option.

Comment: Please, If I have 500 songs ,so what must i do in this case , and each song have 4mb size ?

Comment: Then Go with Second Option.

Comment: Thanks sir, Please, Do you have any example how can i do that with the second option ? please

Comment: You can check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716244/how-to-play-a-music-file-using-url-link-in-iphone

Comment: Thanks sir, I know these steps, but the section:"  User's data plan will be used in each download from server" , I don't know how can i do it.